# How to send DM specific user with id?

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a bot that sends me DM, but it has error

It is my code:

```py
member = client.get_user(int(my id))
await member.send('abc')
```

And error:

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you replace '1234567890' with your own user ID

```
user = client.get_user(1234567890)
await user.send("Hi!", tts=True)
```

Example -

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx):
    user = client.get_user(1234567890)
    await user.send("Hi!", tts=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Before you do anything

First, make sure the bot is in some way connected to you, whether that be you share a guild or you already have a DM channel open with the bot. Second, make sure you allow DMs from shared server members or strangers so that the bot's DM won't be blocked.

### Code

Instead of naming your variable "`member`", let's name it something more appropriate since you are retrieving a `User` object instead of a `Member`. Next, you want to test if you and the bot share a DM channel, if not the bot will create one, and then you can send the message.

```py
user = client.get_user(int('0123456789'))

if not (dm_channel := user.dm_channel):
    dm_channel = await user.create_dm()
await dm_channel.send('abc')
```

Comment: It raised error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dm_channel'

Comment: @Tamong Did you make sure the user's ID you are using is in some way connected to the bot? And did you also make sure your bot's [intentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents) allows DMs?

Comment: If for whatever reason you are still retrieving a `None` from calling `get_user()`, you can use `fetch_user()` which will make an API call to get the `User` object. This is only recommended if the user you are trying to DM is not in any way connected to the bot. The `fetch_user()` documentation can be found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user).